# MySQL statement always set value to 0 when UPDATE SET

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My MySQL statement (wich I used 4 days to find a working one) SHOULD take 1 given value and check 3 different columns if they are filled or NULL. If the column got a value, it goes to the next column. If that column is NULL, it shall write the given value into that cell.

Unfortunately my statement is able to fetch that column, but when I try to SET the value, it is always set to 0. When i try to +1 the existing value it works with no problems.

Statement:

```
UPDATE `license` SET
  `hardwareid1` = IF( `hardwareid1` = 123,`hardwareid1` = 987, `hardwareid1`) ,
  `hardwareid2` = IF( `hardwareid2` = 123, `hardwareid2` = 987, `hardwareid2` )
  WHERE `code` = 99
```

Where the `= 123` is, in production I'll use `IS NULL` the `987` stands for the example value from "$value"

So if hardwareid1 is really `123` it doestn write `987` but `0` instead.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE  license
SET     hardwareID3 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID3 IS NULL
                                THEN 987 
                                ELSE hardwareID3 END,
        hardwareID2 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND 
                                hardwareID2 IS NULL 
                                THEN 987 
                                ELSE hardwareID2 END,
        hardwareID1 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NULL 
                                THEN 987 
                                ELSE hardwareID1 END
WHERE   code = 99
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aa93/1)

What the query does is when `hardwareID1 IS NULL` the new value `987` will be inserted on the column. At the same time, the value of `hardwareID2` will also be changed if `hardwareID1` has a value and `hardwareID2` is null. Otherwise, all their value will retain.

Comment: UPDATE  license
SET     hardwareID1 = IF(hardwareID1 = 123, 987, hardwareID1),
        hardwareID2 = IF(hardwareID1 = 55, 987, hardwareID2)
WHERE   code = 99

tried this, works for the first column but never for the second

Comment: Holy crap you are a genius :) why is the MySQL documentation that hard to understand and people here are always this awesome :) for the 3rd column ill just have to add another "hardwareid2 ...." right?

Comment: Just a little fix, your statement fills ALL columns where NULL, but it should only fill the first that is null :) if 1 got a value and 2 and 3 are NULL only 2 should get value

Comment: Yeah it worked i copy pasted it and try with all columns NULL, but it then fills all NULL columns with the value "987" instead of stopping after the first fill in

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry to ask you once again, but I didnt find a solution to some further extension. Your code works all fine, but now I need to ONLY update the column when the value I want to update doesnt exist. at the moment with every call the statement inserts the value but not looking if the value is already in some solumn

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, but shouldn't your SQL look more like this?

```
`hardwareid1`=CASE
WHEN `hardwareid1`= NULL THEN set_to_xy
```